# How does the assignment proceed in this iteration (TeX)?

Tags: tex-core, algorithms, expansion, loops, variable

In the famous **The TeXbook** (Twentieth printing, revised, May 1991), I've found this algorithm (Appendix D: Dirty Tricks, pag. 373),

```
\newcount\m \newtoks\t \m=\n \t={}
\loop \ifnum\m>0 \t=\expandafter{\the\t *} \advance\m-1 \repeat
\edef\asts{\the\t}
```

Trying to understand how the *stomach* of TeX works, I've changed the algorithm above to this, which traces the evolution of value of variable **\t** in the loop iteration (by initial assumption).

```
\def\n{5}
\newcount\m \newtoks\t \m=\n \t={}
%output during the loop
In the loop:
\loop \ifnum\m>0 \t \t=\expandafter{\the\t *} \advance\m-1 \repeat
\edef\asts{\the\t}
Resulting macro expansion of \char`\\asts: \asts
```

And, surprisingly to me, the respective output showed a sequence of 5 **=*** written during the loop phase and a empty macro expansion to **\asts**.

Could someone give me a hand in order to clarify such behavior?

I am using TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020/Debian),kpathsea version 6.3.2.

By the way, is it possible to define a command/cs without braces? (e.g.,\def\n{5})

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you want to output a toks register you have to use `\the\t`, your `\t \t` is equivalent to `\t=\t`.

Comment: ohhh of course! but why does calling \t crash \asts?

Comment: what do you mean by crash? \asts is  empty as you never put something in \t then, The  `=\expandafter{\the\t *} ` is simply printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the loop you added

```
\t \t=\expandafter{\the\t *}
```

but `\t \t` is equivalent to `\t=\t` and assigns `\t` to itself so this is a no-op and equivalent to

```
=\expandafter{\the\t *}
```

which is the same as

```
=\the\t *
```

But as you no longer are assigning anything to `\t` `\the\t` is always empty so this is

```
=*
```

and just typeset `=*` once on each iteration.

You intended

```
\the\t \t=\expandafter{\the\t *}
```

then `\the\t` would show the current contents of `\t`, and the second `\t` would, as intended be the left hand side of an assignment, setting a new value of `\t` to be the old value and a `*`.

> By the way, is it possible to define a command/cs without braces? (e.g.,\def\n{5})

braces (or at least some characters of catcode 1 and 2) are mandatory in `\def` although `\n` could have been declared as a count register with `\newcount\n`  then braces would not be allowed and the assignment would have the syntax `\n=5`